# Why this error in the TikZ and preview package?

Tags: tikz-pgf, preview

This minimal example produces an error (undefined control sequences):

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{preview}

\begin{document}

Hello.

\end{document}
```

Once the tikz package is removed, it compiles fine. Removing either usepackage commands allows the program to compile. Moreover, including both, but adding the [active] option to preview allows the script to compile.

I've pasted the log file [here](http://pastebin.com/iddnCY9w).

Comment: See http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/316/ and http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/315/.

Comment: I looked at the documentation. if I call `preview.sty` with `\usepackage[active]{preview}`, it does run.

Comment: @sgmoye: as I noted in the post, calling with active runs, but preview should work without.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: forgive for the question, but I can't seem to locate the pfgutil-latex.def file I'm supposed to edit.

Comment: Run `kpsewhich pgfutil-latex.def` on the command line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ulrike Fischer has noted that this is a current bug report listed [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/316/) and [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/315/). I include a short guide so as to preserve the suggested solution.

Run `kpsewhich pgfutil-latex.def` on the command line to detect the location of the def file. Search for an \AtBeginDocument command that addresses the preview package. Change the previous codeblock to the following:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
\@ifpackageloaded{preview}{%
% Ok, package loaded. Swap definitions of everyshi.sty's shipout
% and preview.sty's shipout:
\ifPreview
\let\shipout\@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout%This is the null version of \shipout, created by preview and saved by everyshi
\let\@EveryShipout@Org@Shipout\pr@shipout% This is the original shipout
\let\pr@shipout\@EveryShipout@Shipout%
\fi
}{}%
}
```