# Workaround for too many pages when using preview with pgf or tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, preview

The following document produces a PDF with two pages, while only one is called for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage[active]{preview}
\begin{document}
  Text
  \begin{preview}HELLO\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

While this is a [known bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/316/) (where I also borrowed the MWE, thanks Ulrike), I'd be curious to know if a workaround at the user level exists, especially one that does not involve changing system files (as in [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/202550/8057)).

(A DVI user also wondered: [Does tikz 2.1 no longer work with the preview package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17080/8057) The question here is about `pdflatex`.)

Comment: Has the bug been reported? The bug you linked to is filed against PGF/TiKZ but, if I understand the problem correctly, the bug is actually in `preview`?

Comment: @cfr: Well, `preview` is fine as long as `pgf` is *not* loaded. On the other hand, `pgf` does not seem to be affected by `preview`. (Loading `pgf` seems to involve `\AtBeginDocument` at some point, so the order of package loading is irrelevant.)

Comment: @cfr: The bug report suggests that this is an issue between `preview` and `everyshi`, but after substituting `pgfcore` with `everyshi` the error disappears. I guess `pgf` itself needs to meddle with `\shipout`.

Comment: It doesn't follow that the bug is in PGF. I'm not saying it isn't - only that the bug report you linked to suggests that it is. If it isn't, you should provide that information in the discussion of that bug. There evidently was a related bug in PGF at one point, but that one seems to have been fixed in 1.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A user only needs to save the definition of `\shipout` just before `\begin{document}`, and restore it afterwards. Surprisingly, this also works when `preview` is loaded with the `delayed` option.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{pgfcore}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}

\let\myshipout\shipout
\begin{document}
  \let\shipout\myshipout

  Text
  \begin{preview}HELLO\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have some doubts that this can work. Did you check if the page nodes of tikz still works? Beside this: the patch on sourceforge is not from me, I made only the bug report.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Thanks. Simple tikz figures do work, but I haven't checked page nodes. (In the end, there must be a reason why PGF bothers to play with shipout...) What would be a better way for a user-level patch?