# Croping Tikz animation out of a beamer presentation (producing empty pages)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, standalone, preview

I've a beamer presentation and want to use the tikz pirctures inside rendered as svgs. So far no problem, but compiling the code via `pdflatex` the following (minimal) example results in four pages, every second page empty.

```
\documentclass[beamer,tikz,preview,multi]{standalone}                                                                    

\begin{document}                                                                                                         
\begin{standaloneframe}                                                                                                  
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                                                      

\node[draw](t){AAA};                                                                                                     
\node[above of=t]{ {\visible<2>{BBB}} };                                                                                 

\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                        
\end{standaloneframe}                                                                                                    
\end{document}
```

Result: [image]

- I need `preview` for cropping the tikzpicture - without `preview` it is working fine (but not cropped)
- Same result for `latex` and `pdflatex` - always double pages
- `crop` is not working either or seems to be the legacy solution

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong? Nothing found in manual

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I can confirm this problem is due to the presence of the `preview` option... how to solve it... no idea! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Digging deep I found this 9 day old  [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235733/workaround-for-too-many-pages-when-using-preview-with-pgf-or-tikz/) on stackexchange.com . The problem is depending on pgf and the preview package (seems to be a bug). A working solution is to save \shipout before \begin{document} and restore it afterwards (thank you krlmlr!).

```
\documentclass[beamer,tikz,preview,multi]{standalone}                                                                    

\let\myshipout\shipout
\begin{document}      
\let\shipout\myshipout

\begin{standaloneframe}                                                                                                  
\begin{tikzpicture}                                                                                                      

\node[draw](t){AAA};                                                                                                     
\node[above of=t]{ {\visible<2>{BBB}} };                                                                                 

\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                                        
\end{standaloneframe}                                                                                                    
\end{document}
```