# package animate: How to convert a pdf animation created with transparencies to gif?

Tags: animate, gif, convert

I wrote a pdf animation with the `animate` package using transparencies.

[image: construction-ove]

To be able to show this gif, on S.E, I created not transparencies but images and I could convert it into gif with imagemagick in this way:

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -background white -alpha remove thepdf.pdf result.gif
```

But I wrote it with transparencies in the `animateinline` environment of the `animate` package and the `pdf` file is animated.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

% creation of the ove.txt timeline file
\newwrite\Fichier 
\immediate\openout\Fichier=ove.txt
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,6}{
\immediate\write\Fichier{::\n x0}
}

\immediate\closeout\Fichier% always close the file

\newcommand{\Debut}{% Systematic start of drawing
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (4,2.5);}
\newcommand{\Fin}{\end{tikzpicture} }% Systematic end of drawing
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,begin={\Debut},end={\Fin},timeline=ove.txt]{1.5}
    % perpendicular straight - transparent 0
    \draw[thick] (-2.5,0)--(4,0);
    \draw[thick] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5);
\newframe% circle - transparent 1
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\newframe%  half-line 1 - transparent 2
    \draw[thick] (0,-2)--(3,1);
\newframe%  half-line 2 - transparent 3
    \draw[thick] (0,2)--(3,-1);
\newframe%  arc 1 - transparent 4
    \draw[thick](0,2)arc[start angle=90,end angle=45,radius=4cm];
\newframe%  arc 2 - transparent 5
    \draw[thick](0,-2)arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-45,radius=4cm];
\newframe%  arc 3 - transparent 6
    \draw[thick]([xshift=2cm]45:1.171573cm)arc[start angle=45,end angle=-45,radius=1.171573cm];             
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

I tried to convert these animated pdf into a gif and I didn't succeed.

Is it possible to convert an animated pdf file created with transparencies in this way to gif? If so, how?

Comment: Do I understand the questions correctly: you want the .gif without the white background?

Comment: @samcarter  with or without background, whatever, I just want to easily convert to gif without having to completely rewrite the animation with a succession of images.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420405/36296

Comment: @samcarter That's a good lead. I see this looks possible, the animateinline environment has been modified, but I don't know how or why (I don't understand this code).

Comment: I left a comment below the ship answer. I hope @AlexG is able to take a look at your question.

Comment: @samcarter Thanks a lot, I hope Alex can answer:)

Comment: @samcarter Alex just did, it's beautiful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of **`animate`** version `[2018/08/22]`, producing multipage output from animation frames is easily done by setting **`export`** as a class option to **`standalone`** or as a package option to **`animate`**. Use the conversion program of your choice (e. g. `convert`) to make an animated GIF from the PDF output.

This also works for animations that make use of package `animate`'s **`timeline`** feature (as requested by the OP):

[image: construction-ove]

```
\documentclass[export]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

% creation of the ove.txt timeline file
\newwrite\Fichier 
\immediate\openout\Fichier=ove.txt
\foreach \n in {0,1,...,6}{
\immediate\write\Fichier{::\n x0}
}

\immediate\closeout\Fichier% always close the file

\newcommand{\Debut}{% Systematic start of drawing
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (4,2.5);}
\newcommand{\Fin}{\end{tikzpicture} }% Systematic end of drawing
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,begin={\Debut},end={\Fin},timeline=ove.txt]{1.5}
    % perpendicular straight - transparent 0
    \draw[thick] (-2.5,0)--(4,0);
    \draw[thick] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5);
\newframe% circle - transparent 1
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\newframe%  half-line 1 - transparent 2
    \draw[thick] (0,-2)--(3,1);
\newframe%  half-line 2 - transparent 3
    \draw[thick] (0,2)--(3,-1);
\newframe%  arc 1 - transparent 4
    \draw[thick](0,2)arc[start angle=90,end angle=45,radius=4cm];
\newframe%  arc 2 - transparent 5
    \draw[thick](0,-2)arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-45,radius=4cm];
\newframe%  arc 3 - transparent 6
    \draw[thick]([xshift=2cm]45:1.171573cm)arc[start angle=45,end angle=-45,radius=1.171573cm];             
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you so much for this wonderful update!

Comment: @AlexG Fantastic! I knew you can answer this!

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: @AndréC One downside: Speed changes that may have been defined in the timeline file are not taken into account. These must be newly defined in the GIF making step.

Comment: This is not a problem, speed changes can be created with ImageMagick when creating the gif. The key is to be able to easily create a gif without having to rewrite the code yourself. Bravo!

Answer (score 4):

An alternative of @samcarters elegant proposal is based on [@samcarter's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/426912/121799). It is fairly easy to produce animated gifs from beamer animations. In this case you only have to replace `\newframe` by `\pause`. <s>Unfortunately, I could not make crop work with an animated frame (without `\pause` it works), so I had to mess around with dimensions. It would be great if some beamer expert could fix that, I would be more than happy to remove that proposal then, especially if that beamer expert is the one mentioned above. ;-)</s> **UPDATE**: I found [this very nice answer whose votes I just doubled](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/237364/121799), which uses tricks of [this great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/235750/121799). No more cropping by hand!

```
\documentclass[beamer,tikz,preview,multi]{standalone}                                                                    
\let\myshipout\shipout
\begin{document}      
\let\shipout\myshipout

\begin{standaloneframe}                                                                                                  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (4,2.5);
    % perpendicular straight - transparent 0
    \draw[thick] (-2.5,0)--(4,0);
    \draw[thick] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5);
\pause% circle - transparent 1
    \draw[thick] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\pause%  half-line 1 - transparent 2
    \draw[thick] (0,-2)--(3,1);
\pause%  half-line 2 - transparent 3
    \draw[thick] (0,2)--(3,-1);
\pause%  arc 1 - transparent 4
    \draw[thick](0,2)arc[start angle=90,end angle=45,radius=4cm];
\pause%  arc 2 - transparent 5
    \draw[thick](0,-2)arc[start angle=-90,end angle=-45,radius=4cm];
\pause%  arc 3 - transparent 6
    \draw[thick]([xshift=2cm]45:1.171573cm)arc[start angle=45,end angle=-45,radius=1.171573cm];             
\end{tikzpicture}                                                                                              
\end{standaloneframe}                                                                                                    
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is why I think this is an interesting possibility. For beamer there exist a number of tools that can help one with animations, IMHO the most notable example is given by [aobs-styles](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz). Here is an example based on the [post that has lead to that super useful library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/121799).

```
\documentclass[beamer,tikz,preview,multi]{standalone} 
\tikzset{semivisible on/.style={alt={#1{opacity=0.5,text opacity=0.5}{}}}}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles} 
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}                                                                  
\let\myshipout\shipout
\begin{document}      
\let\shipout\myshipout

\begin{standaloneframe}  
% example based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/121799                                                                                                
\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, concept color=gray!50, font=\sffamily, text=white]

  \tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={font=\sf, sibling angle=90,level
  distance = 30mm}}
  \node[concept,scale=0.7] {beings}
    [clockwise from=135]
        child[concept color=red, visible on=<1>,semivisible on=<{4,2}>]{
        node[concept,scale=0.7]{ducks} } 
        child[concept color=blue, visible on=<2>,semivisible on=<{1,3}>]{
        node[concept,scale=0.7]{marmots} } 
        child[concept color=orange, visible on=<3>,semivisible on=<{2,4}>]{
        node[concept,scale=0.7]{koala bears} } 
        child[concept color=green!50!black, visible on=<4>,semivisible on=<{3,1}>]{
        node[concept,scale=0.7]{squirrels} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{standaloneframe}                                                                                                    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A very ingenious idea, thank you very much :)

Comment: You said "It is fairly easy to produce animated gifs from beamer animations." Can you explain that right here or would you prefer that I ask a new question about it?

Comment: @AndréC I am only using your conversion chain `convert -delay 10 -loop 0 -background white -alpha remove thepdf.pdf result.gif` (modulo some `-density` and a different value for `delay`). That is, if you run one of these snippets and then run that `convert` command, you have an animated gif. If you want a transparent background, you may need [these conversion chains](http://phyletica.org/imagemagick/).